# UNION ALL in the same table, results in different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union-all

I am new to SQL and I'm stuck with something that for sure is easy to solve, but is driving me crazy. I have a huge AS400 txt data export from where I need to get some data. Using single query, I get the right numbers, but I was wondering if there's a way to write a single query that gives a table with the four results, each one in a single column.

These are the four queries:

```
SELECT COUNT([DATA1]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1] FROM STATUS);
SELECT COUNT([DATA2]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1], [DATA2], [DATA3] FROM STATUS);
SELECT COUNT([DATA3]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1], [DATA2], [DATA3], [TAL] FROM STATUS);
SELECT SUM([UNITS]) AS TOTAL FROM STATUS;
```

Tried with UNION ALL, but all the results show up in the same column.

Is there a way to do this? Get the four numbers in a single query, and each result in a different column.

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output??

Comment: Unrelated, but: the first query can be simplified to `select count(distinct data1) from status;` (although I would expect that SQL Server is smart enough to do that by itself)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The DISTINCT is necessary because in the columns of the document, the same number is repeated several times. The idea is to obtain how many unique numbers are stored in the column. For example, let's say column 1 has: number 10 repeated five times and number 12 repeated seven times. What I need to obtain is the count of how many unique numbers are stored in the column. In this example, two.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT([DATA1]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1] FROM STATUS)) [DATA1],
(SELECT COUNT([DATA2]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1], [DATA2], [DATA3] FROM STATUS)) [DATA2],
(SELECT COUNT([DATA3]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1], [DATA2], [DATA3], [TAL] FROM STATUS)) [DATA3],
(SELECT SUM([UNITS]) AS TOTAL FROM STATUS) [UNITS];
```

There's probably room for further improvements regarding all the subqueries, but with this query you should get all the `COUNT` results in different columns of one single row.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I needed to add a "from STATUS" at the end of the query in order to make it work. After editing a bit your query to suit my needs (add some WHERE, nothing else), I get the correct results in different columns, but repeated in thousands of rows instead a single row.

Comment: This probably happes due to the added `FROM STATUS` at the end. Maybe you should include a `CREATE TABLE ...` script in your question and also add the modified query so we're working on a common model.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking in SQL Server 2008 and I noticed that for queries taking count(Data2) and Count(Data3) we may need to specify an alias for the inner select with distinct, inorder to get correct result.

```
SELECT DATA1_CNT = (SELECT COUNT([DATA1]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1] FROM STATUS)),
DATA2_CNT =(SELECT COUNT([DATA2]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1], [DATA2], [DATA3] FROM STATUS) d1),
DATA3_CNT = (SELECT COUNT([DATA3]) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATA1], [DATA2], [DATA3], [TAL] FROM STATUS) d2),
UNITS_SUM = (SELECT SUM([UNITS]) AS TOTAL FROM STATUS)
```